# read()/recv() successfully but buffer is unchanged and empty

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am writing a client to read the data sent back from a server over socket under TCP with c script on LINUX.

The server is running forever and I validate if I can get the reply with `netcat localhost [PORT_NUMBER]` already. The server is in LISTEN state when checking with `netstat -nap`

The recv() function returns expected number of bytes, but buffer becomes empty and strlen(buffer) is 0. I also try changing to read() which I did not expect a different result, and the same problem was shown.

This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc, msg_rep_size = 1200, msg_size = 100;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[msg_size], server_reply[msg_rep_size];

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(31114); // PORT_NUMBER

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        printf("connect error");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connected");


    while (1)
    { 
    // send some data
    bzero(message, msg_size);
    strncpy(message, "REQUEST\n", msg_size);

    if (send(socket_desc, message, msg_size, 0) < 0)
    {
        printf("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Data Send\n");

    // Receive a reply from the server
    bzero(server_reply, msg_rep_size);
    int read_result = recv(socket_desc, server_reply, msg_rep_size, 0); 

    if (read_result < 0)
    {
        printf("Receive failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Reply received\n");
        printf("read_result: %d\n", read_result);
        printf("strlen(server_reply): %d\n", (int)strlen(server_reply));
        printf("Reply: %s\n", server_reply);
    }
    usleep(8);
}

return 0;
}
```

The printed result in bash is

```
Data send
Reply received
read_result: 1108 
strlen(server_reply): 0
Reply:
```

The same result is shown if I change from

```
int read_result = recv(socket_desc, server_reply, msg_rep_size, 0);
```

to

```
int read_result = read(socket_desc, server_reply, msg_rep_size);
```

Thank you for your help. I am new to socket programming and could not track what is going on.

PS. The expected size of bytes from reply is 1108, which is correct. I intended to put maximum size as 1200 to confirm that correct number of byte is received.

PS2. Please feel free to also comment on the coding style of low-level c as well.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after EVERY opening brace.  Unindent before every closing brace. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `printf("strlen(server_reply): %d\n", (int)strlen(server_reply));`  do not use `strlen()` on data read from a server, because there can be embedded NUL bytes.  Instead use the value (if above 0) returned from the call to `recv()`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Reply: %s\n", server_reply);`  this will only work if the message received from the server does not contain any NUL bytes   better to have a loop that calls `putc()` for each character in the received message

Comment: `strlen(server_reply)` is irrelevant. You don't know whether there is a trailing null at all. There could be no nulls at all, or several,including.one right at the beginning. To print the reply properly and see whether a problem exists at all, use `printf("%.*s\n", read_result, server_reply)`. No need for a loop @user3629249

Comment: when compiling, enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: Mind `strlen()` simply tells you the index of the first null byte, it is designed to be used in valid C strings and is not binary safe. If whatever the server is sending you starts with a `\0`, `strlen()` will return 0, but it does not mean the server didn't send you anything.

Comment: @EJP: `%.*s` will stop at the first NUL because it prints a maximum of `read_result` bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no evidence here of a problem, only bad code. If `recv()` returned 1088 it certainly transferred 1088 bytes into the buffer. Clearly the data received starts with a null byte. To print it correctly, use

```
printf("%.*s\n", read_result, server_reply);
```

NB:

1. 'The expected size of bytes from reply is 1108, which is correct'. No it isn't. There is no 'expected size'. TCP is a streaming protocol. If `recv()` returns a positive number, the byte count transferred can be anything from 1 upwards to the buffer length supplied. You have to code a *loop* to be sure of getting exactly *N* bytes.
2. Before assuming it is positive, you must also check `read_result` for zero, which indicates that the peer has disconnected. Do not omit this step.
3. `strlen(server_reply)` is irrelevant. You don't know whether there is a trailing null at all. There could be no nulls at all, or several, including, as in this case, one right at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much,

So I added a loop of reading each character and the reply is shown now.

Comment: You don't need to read a byte at a time, but while the total transfer count is less than expected you need to advance the pointer and decrement the length parameter and re-read. Reading one byte at a time is extremely inefficient.

Comment: If `server_reply` starts with a NUL byte, `printf("%.*s\n", read_result, server_reply);` will only print a newline.